# How get android location working without play services?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I was trying to debloat my system from all Google Apps, including Play Services...but I noticed something wrong about position.
Almost all gps/navigation apps use the location provided by play services, and without it, they aren't locking the position (of course).
Is there any workaround about this? And why apps do not use the so cool location Manager? It's kinda frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is how Google manages Android. They do make the manual pages so they can say whatever in them to throw you to their fishing net. For example see the huge note in top of [Location and Maps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/) manual.

> Note: This is a guide to the Android framework location APIs in the
>   package android.location. The Google Location Services API, part of
>   Google Play Services, provides a more powerful, high-level framework
>   that automates tasks such as location provider choice and power
>   management. Location Services also provides new features such as
>   activity detection that aren't available in the framework API.
>   Developers who are using the framework API, as well as developers who
>   are just now adding location-awareness to their apps, should strongly
>   consider using the Location Services API.
>
> To learn more about the Location Services API, see Google Location
>   Services for Android.

As you can see, the developers are directed to NOT use Android framework APIs. But why you think Google does not develop Android instead? Because using Google APIs will tie you to Google so you can't live without it. It is a way of creating addiction.

In addition, this also helps Google to collect location information every time your app requests location. So basically Google feeds on your apps location data like a leech.

Google really balanced Android in a way that other companies can use the OS. But the OS will be useless unless you install Google services. It is somewhat evil perhaps (but who will notice that right?), but a win/win scenario, for Google that is.

To answer your question, no the app's which were coded to use Google API services can not function without it.

Comment: could you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284432/how-to-create-location-foreground-service-without-google-play-service